# Возможно ли создавать таблицы бд во время выполнения программы и как это можно реализовать с помощью EF?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Допустим у меня есть база данных инструментов и различной утвари для постройки дома, починки машины и т.д. (ключи, гайки цемент и т.д.).

Но мне захотелось добавить кирпичи в мой базу данных, естественно кирпичи будут отличаться от других материалов/инструментов, а значит будут иметь различные характеристики (т.е мне нужно, например при подходе Code first в Entity Framework писать новый класс и применять миграцию и т.д.).

Есть ли возможность из приложения менять мою базу данных создавая и удаляя таблицы по моему усмотрению из бд и как?

При этом бы хотелось иметь возможность выборки данных и сортировки данных добавленных таблиц по любым полям.

Вот такая идея, но как реализовать не знаю. Конечно , идеально было, если бы такие возможности предоставляла EF.

Comment: Допустим, добавилась новая таблица в БД. Как вы к ней обратитесь в EF? Ведь нужно добавить в код C# новый класс, смапленный на эту таблицу и перекомпилировать код.

Comment: Добавлять отдельную таблицу для каждого материала - это, мягко говоря, не лучшая архитектура БД. Посмотрите в сторону [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет нельзя, так как на этапе компиляции должно быть все известно.
2. Странная какая-то структура под каждый кирпич делать свою таблицу. Создайте таблицу товары, а на нее пусть ссылается таблица с характеристиками [ID,Prodct_id,Name,Value]. В итоге, через простое соединение вы получаете все необходимые характеристики.