# C# Создание таблиц в EntityFramework

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает. Каким инструментом EF можно создавать таблицу из кода. Обшарил весь интернет, не нашел ничего дельного. Кто-то предлагает сырую библиотеку, другие ссылаются на Migration, но миграция, выполняется только один раз. Мне необходимо проверять на существование таблицы, и при ее отсутствии создавать ее. На сегодня использую во такой код.

```
        try
        {
            var milkoscan = new ConnectionMilkoscan();
            milkoscan.Database.Migrate();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Но как я сказал ранее, он выполняется всего один раз, до тех пор пока я не очищу таблицу _efmigrationshistory.

Comment: Вы либо пользуетесь не тем инструментом и вам EF не нужен (не предназначен для динамических таблиц - [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/971612/213987), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972386/213987)...) либо неправильно готовите EF. Ну вот ради бога, объясните, зачем вам удалять служебную таблицу migrations history? Она нужна для фреймворка. Штатный способ: используйте миграции, не удаляйте таблицу. Либо, блин, ну так осознайте что EF под ваши задачи не подходит и откажитесь от EF. Программирование во многом - о выборе правильного инструмента под задачу.

Comment: Механизм миграций позволяет дописывать миграции при подходе Code First: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/ Ну если конечно это надо делать не в рантайме в процессе работы, а только при обновлениях.

Comment: в том то и дело, что мне не нужно удалять служебную таблицу. То есть вы хотите сказать, что для создания таблиц из кода EF  лучше не использовать?

Comment: Вы так нечётко описываете сценарий, что непонятно хорошо использовать или плохо использовать. У меня вот есть приложение, есть база, EF знает схему базы, один раз обновил схему до нужной версии приложения - и работает с этой базой. И если я как разработчик добавляю какое-то поле - я это описываю ещё одной миграцией и всё, она запустится, обновит базу до нужного состояния, не удаляя данные, таблицы - просто добавит столбец и так годами миграция за миграцией база развивается. А вы зачем удаляете под нож таблицу миграций и тут же говорите "но мне это не нужно". А что? По ссылкам моим ваши кейсы?